Unable to find version '16.2.5' of DevExpress packages
I have a .NET application that uses DevExpress version 16.2.5.0. I am continuously getting "NuGet Package restore failed" error when I build the project. I have inherited the source code from another company. I have about 8 package sources, but Visual Studio 2022 complains DevExpress packages are not found on source. For instance, one such package is DevExpress.BonusSkins.16.2.5.0. The other is DevExpress.Sparkline.Core.16.2.5.0. There are several others. I tried downloading and installing version 16.2.5 of DevExpress without success. The installed DLLs have 16.2 suffix but not 16.2.5. My packages.config file looks like below. Any assistance is appreciated.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="DevExpress.BonusSkins" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Data" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Office.Core" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Pdf.Core" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Printing.Core" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.RichEdit.Core" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Sparkline.Core" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Utils" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.Xpo" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.XtraBars" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.XtraEditors" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.XtraGrid" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.XtraLayout" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.XtraPrinting" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="DevExpress.XtraTreeList" version="16.2.5.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.5.8" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>



Have you tried running "Update-Package –reinstall" in NuGet Package Management Console?

@MarkoJuvančič Yes, I have. I get the following error message when I try to.  Update-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.

I think this version is old and not supported in VS 2022. Try VS 2019.

@ShahramAlemzadeh I am unable to downgrade to VS 2019. Any other suggestions or advice?

@YashDutt, not really unfortunately. Please have a look at Supported Versions, Version History, and IDE Prerequisites. It seems versions below 20 are not supported in VS 2022 at all. May be updating to DevExp V22 and above helps.

@ShahramAlemzadeh I installed VS 2019 and tried but still got same errors. I will try updating DevExp to a newer version, I hope it works and doesn't break.
